# Unable to give required width, and height for collectionview cell in swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have gicen collectionview height as 300 and added cell with imageview and label
for label given constraints `bottom, leading, trailing = 10` and for image given top, leading, trailing = 10, bottom = 40

[image]

**code:** with this I am getting wired o/p. I can't even see label and too broad imageview. **I need 200 height and total screen width**. how to fix this issue? how to give proper cell size to show image and label. please guide me.

```
class CollPagingViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionviewCellSize: UICollectionView!

var cellArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionviewCellSize.delegate = self
    collectionviewCellSize.dataSource = self
    if let layout = collectionviewCellSize.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        }
 }
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let height = 200.0
    print("cell size:\n width: \(width) heigth: \(height)")
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellArray.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollCell2", for: indexPath) as! CollCell2
    cell.textLbl.text = cellArray[indexPath.item]
        return cell
}
```

o/p:

> width: 414.0 heigth: 200.0

[image]

**EDIT:** with this code getting correct cellsize but i want using `sizeForItemAt` method. how? why i am not getting correct cell size using `sizeForItemAt`?

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionviewCellSize.delegate = self
    collectionviewCellSize.dataSource = self

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let width = collectionviewCellSize.frame.width
    let height = collectionviewCellSize.frame.height

    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    self.collectionviewCellSize.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```

Comment: If you want all screen width, why not use table view instead ?

Comment: @PtitXav, you mean collectionview inside tableview cell? i want horizontal scroll with paging also paging is working but cell size is bad

Comment: Ok, i missed the point if horizontal scrolling. So try to have a look at UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout . There is exactly what you need. Look at the [demo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views)  for some code to start with.

Comment: @PtitXav, if i add UICollectionViewFlowLayout in viewDidload then getting correct size but why the same width and height is not giving proper size with `sizeForItemAt ` method? i need cell size with this method. any idea? is there any bigger calculations need.. i just given image and label in cell with proper constraints. edited viewdidload code in my post too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding UI elements such as `UICollectionView` there are a lot of "default" settings that get applied.

In this case, one notable setting is **Estimated Cell Size**. If we add a collection view to a view controller, the default is **Automatic** -- which tells UIKit to use the cell's content to calculate the size... *even if we've implemented `sizeForItemAt`.

So, add one line to your flow layout configuration:

```
    if let layout = collectionviewCellSize.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        
        // need this line
        layout.estimatedItemSize = .zero
    }
```

Now, you should get the proper cell sizing.

As a side note - you don't want to use `UIScreen.main.bounds.width`! If the collection view is constrained to the safe area (which is should be), or if the user is running your app in multitasking mode on an iPad, `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` will not give you what you want.

Instead, use the collection view's frame:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    // don't use screen!
    //let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    
    // use collection view frame
    let width = collectionView.frame.width
    let height = 200.0
    print("cell size:\n width: \(width) heigth: \(height)")
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)

}
```